# Where can I find a high-resolution full map of Toril?

Tags: forgotten-realms, maps

Is there anywhere I can find a full map of Toril? I'd like one with Kara-tur, Faerun, etc in a good resolution, at around the Time of Troubles. Instead I just find low resolution maps like [this one](https://markustay.deviantart.com/art/Faerunian-continent-100337147), which is also missing Anchorome, Maztica, Katashaka, etc.

Comment: As the geography of Toril changes drastically and often (on a geological time scale), from when do you want this map to be?

Comment: How drastic are those changes? like creating new continents? I would like one not much after Times of Troubles

Comment: Large, significant islands appear/disappear. Peninsulas become islands. Major cities become craters. Coastlines move tens of miles. I would call them drastic.

Comment: mm I see, I said around age of Time of Troubles although I wouldnt mind one if it has better resolution of another age, it's just is difficult finding those maps, cannot find them, on the forgottem realm wiki contintents map are cropped and there isnt any good toril map

Comment: Not an answer but related: [there's a list of on which continent is which region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_index_of_Toril) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

Like [this one](http://www.thebigblackmachine.com/thedungeon/the-hamlet/Abeir-Toril-Map.jpg), for example, included at the last post above the footer on [this site](http://www.thebigblackmachine.com/thedungeon/tyranny-of-dragons/the-hamlet.php)?

I'm not aware of any official maps, mind you. I just used Google's image search. :) (Go to Google, enter "Toril" into the search field and hit enter, click the "images" tab, click "tools", click "size", click "Larger than..." from the rolldown menu, and pick a resolution limit. Check the result. If nothing good comes up, try a resolution one step lower. Repeat as needed.)

Comment: mmm so there isnt any "official" map? was hoping to have one like this one but from whole Toril [map](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/forgottenrealms/images/a/a0/Faerun_map.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20080923050218)

Comment: I mean one with town names and keeps